# How to calculate Odds ratio and 95% confidence interval for decile

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I have done logistic regression, a part of result is like below.

```
 Coefficients:
                                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)                         
  (Intercept)                    -1.9056     0.4967  -3.837 0.000125 ***
  GWAS$value                     0.4474     0.1157   3.868 0.000110 ***
```

---

This is the data which I used to do logistic  regression.

```
  ID  Phenotype   value
1 128         0 1.510320
2 193         1 1.956477
3 067         0 2.038308
4 034         1 2.058739
5 159         0 2.066371
6 013         0 2.095866
```

I would like to know how to calculate Odds Ratio and 95% Confidence interval for the decile of the value? My purpose is out put a plot, the y axis is OR(95%CI) and the x axis is the decile of the value in my data Can anyone please tell me how can I calculate this in R?
This is the example of the figure. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuJJC.png)

Comment: you want a 95% CI of the predicted effect at every decile? It's a bit odd.. you have two straight lines, are you aware of this?

Comment: Two straight lines? Sorry I'm not sure what you mean.                                        Ok, I change another question: I have a polygenic risk score model, and I get the value of the data after I use this model to calculate. So, I want to output a figure like this link: https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article/figure/image?size=large&id=10.1371/journal.pone.0056128.g002                                                    Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Ok yes, you have to categorize your samples according to the value, and regress against a factor. In your example, value will be categorized used predictor for phenotype. You cannot use it as continuous

Comment: can you dput your data? I don't think what you showed is everything. Otherwise I have to use some available dataset

Comment: Umm...it's really the head of my data, I only use this file. I use this file to do logistic regression, and use predict() function to get the probability , so finally I can get the odds ratio of each sample(OR=P/1-P). But I am not sure....is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have your data, so I cannot obtain the right model for you. The trick is to make the predictor ordinal, and use that to regress your response variable. After that you just plot the CI of each group, and join the lines if need be. Below I used an example dataset, and if you use the same steps, you should get the plot below:

```
library(tidyverse)
ldata <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
# we break gre column into quintiles
ldata <- ldata %>% mutate(GRE = cut_number(gre,5))

#regression like you did, calculate lor for all quintiles
fit <- glm(admit ~ 0+GRE,data=ldata,family="binomial")

# results like you have
results = coefficients(summary(fit))
# rename second column, SE for plotting
colnames(results)[2] = "SE"
#use ggplot
data.frame(results) %>% 
mutate(X=1:n()) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=X,y=Estimate)) + geom_point()+
geom_line() + 
# 95% interval is 1.96*SE
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=-1.96*SE+Estimate,ymax=1.96*SE+Estimate),width=0.2)+
scale_x_continuous(label=rownames(results))+
xlab("GRE quintiles") +ylab("Log Odds Ratio")
```

[image]